# Making a website (with a database) in html/css/php OR Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Heyy, I'm wondering what would be ideal for creating a website like : http://either.io, I'm not sure if i should make the website from scratch using html/css/php/js etc or use something like Wordpress. Im competent in html/css/php/js however Im not sure if it'll be a waste of time to do it this way as it seems obsolete. The website will have a database, and i also want users to be able to make accounts and submit content to the website, will Wordpress be able to do these functions and if so, will it be easy to manage the database? Also if there is anything else to use, I would love to hear. So for the general question :/ I really didn't know where else to ask! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Also i was look at ruby on rails, would that also be a valid option? Thanks

Comment: Install your own instance of wordpress, and you'll be able to do all these things sooner, and probably much better than you can from scratch as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you should use any CMS (such as Wordpress) for an simple project because there are quite a lot of solutions, components and community support.

Go to custom php(or any other language) project when CMS can't fully cover your planned functionality

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe the website you need to create is simple enough, so Wordpress should make all the job you need. You don't need to build the wheel again.

I recommend you to start by reading Wordpress.org to check the documentation, what you can do with it and how it flow works.

But basically it provides you user authentication and content management, so you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a static site not carrying much data, html css is better. But if you need to store lots of user information it is better to go with wordpress. Any kind of powerful website can be created using wordpress provided having knowledge in php.
Notable websites using wordpress:
     1.[IBM Jobs](https://blog.ibm.jobs/)
     2.[Newyork times](http://www.nytimes.com/)
     3.[Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/)